# Spting Boot OAuth2 with multiple databases

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to implement an application that uses one shared authorization server, but the authorization server looks up for users in different databases.

E.g. I have database A and B, let it be Postgres and Oracle. A and B databases consist of the identical in structure tables and have `users` table. So if an user from database A or B wants to login, authorization server should resolve this correctly (look for A user in A database, B user in B database, ... N user in N database). If user is found and password matches, then oauth server creates a token and stores it inside 'shared' database C, like Redis or Mongo (this is not a problem).

I successfully configured OAuth2 client, resource server and oauth server for one database, but is there a good way to handle such a situation for multiple different databases (data sources)?

Comment: I think the usage of differents databases to store multiple users it's not a good practise , you can make a database to handle user authentication and the other to handle data-storage

Comment: @AhmedRebai Unfortunately, I have no choice. There are many different clients with their own database, with their special only for them users

Comment: This implemntation  will make your application respond lazy , you have to connect to each database and check if the user is autorized to sign-in or not